# Implementing a drop-down combobox in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to implement a hour / minute / (am/pm) control. Something similar to what Hotmail has under their calendar. Does anyone have an idea where to start?

The control, visually, is a textfield; however, clicking it allows you to either enter in a time via typing, or selecting a time from a dropdownlist (which appears underneath the textfield).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you would do with PHP, but rather with a client-side technology like [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/home). I would suggest you look into the [`$.datepicker()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) plugin. This plugin will do what you're asking right out of the box with a single line of JavaScript:

```
$("#mydate").datepicker();
```

Which will result in the following:

[image]

There are a great deal of options and configurations that you can take advantage of to really customize the data the user can select, as well as how the user interacts with the widget in general.

See the documentation for further info: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible entirely in PHP, you need to use JavaScript.

Any reason you cannot use a jQuery or YUI widget?

If you cannot for some reason, you need to start off by binding `onmousedown` event for the textbox and have it draw either a drop-down menu with the date/time.

Hope that helps to give you some direction.

Comment: @user978122 I would encourage you to re-consider. The amount of development that has gone into jQuery UI (for instance) easily trumps anything you'll be able to come up with on your own. Using libraries when they're necessary will save you time, money, and sanity ;)

Comment: @JonathanSampson Orders from on high. ^_^

Comment: @user978122 Just some friendly advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is for generating time in Combo box, which includes minutes.

```
$times = array();

$start = strtotime('8:00am');
$finish = strtotime('12:00am tomorrow');

while($start <= $finish) {
    $times[] = date('g.ia', $start);
    $start += strtotime('+30 min', 0);
}

var_dump($times);
```

I hope this helps you. Thanks.